# Assign an svg file to the src property of the img tag

Tags: reactjs, svg

Today I opened an old react app, I updated the dependencies and now there is a problem with an SVG file. I show you a snippet of the code:

```
.
import landscape from './landscape.svg'
.
.
.
<img src={landscape} className="fill" alt=""></img>
.
.
```

[image]

[image]

The app was created with create-react-app.

I don't know what is happening. I also tried to convert the svg file to a jsx file, but I have still problems.

Comment: Everything here doesn't make sense. Either you want to use the .svg file as an asset. Then it needs to be available on your webserver for download, and the `src` attribute needs to reference the path to that file. Or you want to load the content of the SVG as a component, then the `<img>` tag makes no sense. In this case, it is a precondition that the file is "clean". Yours seems to be produced by Inkscape. If you have designed it yourself with that program, choose the "Save as normal SVG" option. If not, clean up the file, for example with [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/).